# Transactions not being committed although I have "Commit Transaction" statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure-sql-database, ssms

I'm using SQL Azure and trying to do conditional delete in batches for a large table, sample:

```
DECLARE
    @LargestKeyProcessed BIGINT =1,
    @NextBatchMax BIGINT,
    @msg varchar(max) ='';
 
WHILE (@LargestKeyProcessed <= 1000000)
BEGIN
 Begin Transaction
 SET @NextBatchMax = @LargestKeyProcessed + 50000;
  DELETE From mytable
  WHERE Id > @LargestKeyProcessed AND Id <= @NextBatchMax And some logic
  SET @LargestKeyProcessed = @NextBatchMax;
    set @msg=''+@LargestKeyProcessed;
  RAISERROR(@msg, 0, 1) WITH NOWAIT
  Commit Transaction
END
```

After the command gets executed successfully I close the tab but SSMS says there are uncomitted transactions although the commit statement is in every iteration. Also the database size seems to remain the same.

I kindly seek your support in explaining why this happens

Thank you very much

Comment: Rollback the transaction before raising the error.

Comment: @GordonLinoff sorry is rolling back the same as calling "commit transaction"? thanks

Comment: @GordonLinoff I suspect Techy is trying to use `RAISERROR(@msg, 0, 1) WITH NOWAIT` like a `PRINT` statement for instantaneous feedback while the batches are progressing. Severity=0 shouldn't affect the transaction but to be sure I'd move it after the commit.

Comment: Every statement runs inside a transaction. If you don't have one open, by default SQL Server opens one, lets the statement run, then commits it automatically. You're really not gaining much here by doing effectively the same job manually.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning it's true I'm using it like a print statment and not sure this is the best approach

Comment: `implicit_transactions` is it on or off?

Comment: @Charlieface when I run select @@OPTIONS & 2 I get 0 I think it means autocommit

Comment: Just before `begin transaction` insert `select @@trancount;` what do you get? Also, try terminating all statements with `;` apart from `begin` and `while` *EDIT* what about @@trancount after the commit?

Comment: @Charlieface I get 0
I have also tried to use the semicolon but no change
 thanks for the tips

Comment: If taking out the manual transaction management (as I say, it's effectively redundant) still sees the issue happening, then look for a rogue trigger.

Comment: Silly troubleshooting thought--what do you get when you change "DELETE" to "SELECT COUNT(*)"?  This is to make sure you are actually getting rows that match your WHERE condition.  If you get zero--then the problem is in the WHERE.

Comment: @Russ thanks it appears I was calling previously deleted ranges

Comment: @Charlieface
@@trancount is now 6  for both before begin and commit

Comment: Did you try with a semicolon after `commit transaction`? And can you please [edit] in your *full* exact code.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try to add `SET IMPLICIT_TRANSACTIONS OFF` to the sql. As follows to see if solved your issue.

```
DECLARE
    @LargestKeyProcessed BIGINT =1,
    @NextBatchMax BIGINT,
    @msg varchar(max) ='';
 
WHILE (@LargestKeyProcessed <= 1000000)
BEGIN
 SET IMPLICIT_TRANSACTIONS OFF  
 Begin Transaction
 SET @NextBatchMax = @LargestKeyProcessed + 50000;
  DELETE From mytable
  WHERE Id > @LargestKeyProcessed AND Id <= @NextBatchMax And some logic
  SET @LargestKeyProcessed = @NextBatchMax;
    set @msg=''+@LargestKeyProcessed;
  RAISERROR(@msg, 0, 1) WITH NOWAIT
  Commit Transaction
END
```

Comment: unfortunately this didn't help, as soon as I stop the query and close the window it still says there are uncommitted transactions

Comment: Change `SET @NextBatchMax = @LargestKeyProcessed + 50000;`  ->  `SET @NextBatchMax = @LargestKeyProcessed + 10000;` ?

Comment: I have tried variable batch sizes but it's still the same :(